# Change KAFKA_CFG_NUM_PARTITIONS value for a Kafka Topic in kubernetes configuration

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, bitnami

Currently my application has bitnami container for kafka. I want to change the number of partitions in a topic to three. But I don't know where should I do that. When I go to minikube dashboard, I see that there is a KAFKA_CFG_NUM_PARTITIONS. But I don't know where to define that in my project. I have below files

1. Chart.yaml which has

   apiVersion: v2
   name: infra
   type: application
   sources:
   - https:/examplePorject
   dependencies:
   - name: kafka
   version: 14.x.x
   respository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
2. values.yaml
   kafka:
   url: infra-kafka-0.infra-headless:9092
3. statefulset.yaml

I found that there is a property **environment**  and that defines KAFKA_CFG_NUM_PARTITIONS inside of it.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, this ENV variable `KAFKA_CFG_NUM_PARTITIONS` sets the server config `num.partitions`: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/broker-configs.html#brokerconfigs_num.partitions

Which is the default number of partitions that auto created topics will have.

To increase the number of partitions of an existing topic, you can use the `kafka-topics` tool:

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --alter --bootstrap-server <kafka>:9092 --topic <topic-name> --partitions <new-num-partitions>
```

Comment: Thanks for you response . I know this --partitions parameter but I cant really use it in dynamic setup. I have to set/pass this as an environment variable either in chart.yaml or values.yaml. And I don't know where exactly should I do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Pod or Statefulset is where you can edit env vars, but it'll probably also be done in the Helm values file. But that's not going to edit any existing topics

If you want to edit a topic partitions from Kubernetes resources, you'd need to use an Operator such as Strimzi that reads `kind: KafkaTopic` resource definitions

Otherwise, you'll need to use `kafka-topics` CLI, as the other answer shows